# Problems building node.js on Cygwin, please help

Tags: python, windows-7, path, node.js, cygwin

I'm trying to get node.js running on Windows 7. I have no experience with Linux so I've just been blindly following instructions from tutorials I've found, but I'm still unable to build node.js.

What I did:

1. Install Cygwin - the entirety
2. Attempt to build node.js

This is the error I first got:
[image: node build error]

I then followed the commands of two other similar sites and they all resulted in this error (could getting several version of node have caused me more problems? I'm completely clueless on this).

I read somewhere that the Windows version of Python could be causing the problem so I uninstalled my Python 2.7 and added C:\cygwin\bin to the PATH.

That still didn't work and I read somewhere else that I'm supposed to rebaseall so I tried that, but I also got an error for that: [image: rebaseall error]

That's where I'm at now. Have any steps I've taken exacerbated the situation?

Answer (score 2):

Add `-e '/\/sys-root\/mingw\/bin/d'` at line 110 in `/bin/rebaseall` file.
Then re-run `rebaseall -v` and you shouldn't get the error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why did you check out such an old release v0.2.5? When I did it a few weeks ago I just took the latest and ended up with 0.5.0pre, but it would also be reasonable to specify v0.4.3. For instance, type `git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git` to download node, and then:

```
cd node
./configure
make install
```

Secondly, do not rebase by running ash from the CYGWIN shell. Instead, shutdown all Cygwin processes, then use Windows explorer to open the ash.exe binary. Since I have a Windows 7 system without node.js, I decided to follow my instructions and build. Not so easy. I ran into some wierd dll issues that all went away when I ran `./rebaseall` followed by `./perlrebase` from the ash prompt. It seems that rebaseall is not sufficient anymore.

Thirdly, there is a message that makes it sound like you don't have a C compiler. Some googling will lead you to sites telling which Cygwin packages you need, but at minimum install the g++ compiler and that should pull in C as a dependency.

When I did this I simply ran configure and every time there was an error, installed one more Cygwin package to supply the missing piece. Even OpenSSL is available.

Answer (score 1):

See this [pretty helpful blog posting](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/03/16/node-js-on-windows/) - Node on CygWin doesn't work for Node v0.2.5. Use the latest v0.4.0 version instead.

Also consider the post's recommendation of compiling against MinGW instead of in CygWin.

Answer (score 0):

I like cygwin a lot -- but recent releases have become pretty unreliable. Some packages just wont build, and some "standard" apps dont work e.g. gvim's "save as" bombs out on my installation.

A possible solution would be run one of the better **Linux** distributions (ubuntu, fedora, suse etc.) either as a virtual machine or a dual boot setup and do the build inside linux.

Comment: All Kudos to the guys at cygwin for providing a reliable POSIX environment and useful X server. I think the problems have more to do with the flaky underlying OS with all its versions, editions and endless flow of fixes!

Comment: I actually tried installing Ubuntu before I tried Cygwin. I have it on an USB and everything. Unfortunately that didn't go any better than this... I couldn't figure out how to do the partitioning so now I'm here

Answer (score 0):

What I just found is remove the windows based install of Python. After uninstalling this, everything is peachy.